# Gif Image only playing once. Need it to replay each time

Tags: java, image, draw, reload, gif

I don't want to post the entire program on here because that would be too much, but I will post snippets of it and detail where they came from so you have an idea.

Problem: For my class project, I am making a typical space invaders game. When a missile hits a ship an explosion gif is played. The gif only loops once (not continuous). The when the missile hits the alien craft, the gif plays just fine for the first spaceship. However, when I shoot a missile at the second or third,etc, ship the gif does not play again. I believe that it is just playing the last frame of the gif from what I have researched. Is there a way to either reload the gif image to play each time the missile is hits or is there another way to do this?

Here is the link to the image: http://postimg.org/image/v2lljr7cb/

Here is some code:

I have a class called Boom, where the explosion is happening. Here is the code in that class:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.drawImage(getEnemyImg(), x, y, null);
}

public Image getEnemyImg() {
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("src/Boom.gif");
    return ic.getImage();
}
```

I then have another class called GameFrame where everything happens. In it, there are these lines of code specially for the explosion. Here is the code from this class:

```
static ArrayList<Boom> booms = new ArrayList<Boom>();

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    ImageIcon ic = new ImageIcon("src/BackGround.jpg");
    g2d.drawImage(ic.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    player.draw(g2d);

    for (int i = 0; i < booms.size(); i++) {
        Boom bm = booms.get(i);
        bm.draw(g2d);
    }

    Enemy e = new Enemy(200, 400);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    player.update();

    for (int i = 0; i < booms.size(); i++) {
        Boom bm = booms.get(i);
        bm.update();
    }

    checkEnd();

    repaint();

}
```

public static void addBoom(Boom bm) {

```
    booms.add(bm);
}

public static void removeBoom(Boom bm) {
    booms.remove(bm);
}

public static ArrayList<Boom> getBoomList() {
    return booms;
}
```

Finally, here is where the explosion is being added. This happens when the missile hits the alien space craft. This is happening in the Enemy class. Here is the code:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    for (int i = 0; i < GameFrame.getMissileList().size(); i++) {
        Missile m = GameFrame.getMissileList().get(i);
        if (getBounds().intersects(m.getBounds())) {
            GameFrame.removeEnemy(this);
            GameFrame.removeMissile(m);
            GameFrame.addBoom(new Boom(m.getX() -40, m.getY()- 60));
            for(int j = 0; i <GameFrame.getBoomList().size(); i++){
                Boom bm = GameFrame.getBoomList().get(j);
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

I apologize for the wall of text. My professor was unsure of how to do this so I was hoping to get some help from here.

If you have any time to spare, your ideas would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: 1- Don't ever reference the `src` folder in your code, it will not exist once the application is build.  In the case use something more like `getClass().getResource("/Boom.gif");` instead.

Comment: You might need to use `ImageIcon#getImage#flush` to force the reloading of the image...

Comment: MadProgrammer- Thank you. I will make those changes and try what you said and let you know how it works out.